# Postgres Sequences as Default Value for Django Model Field

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I have a PostgreSQL database that is being used by a front-end application built with Django, but being populated by a scraping tool in Node.js. I have made a `sequence` that I want to use across two different tables/entities, which can be accessed by a function (`nexval(serial)`) and is called on every insert. This is not the primary key for these tables, but simply a way to maintain order through some metadata. Using it in Node.js during the insertion of the data into the tables is trivial, as I am using raw SQL queries. However, I am struggling with how to represent this using Django models. There does not seem to be any way to associate this Postgres function with a model's field.

Question:
Is there a way to use a Postgres function as the default value of a Django model field?

Comment: you can create a [custom database type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-model-fields/#custom-database-types), and a [custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#field-api-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My eventual solution:

Override the `save` method of the model, using a raw query to `SELECT nextval('serial')` inside the override, setting that as the value of the necessary field, then call `save` on the parent (`super(PARENT, self).save()`).

Answer (score 3):

you can also set your own function for the `default`

```
from django.db import connection, models

def sequence_id():
  with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("""SELECT nextval('model_someid_seq')""")
    return cursor.fetchone()[0]


class MyModel(models.Model):
  field_id = models.IntegerField(default=sequence_id)
```

Comment: If i do this the sequence runs many times. Easy 30 times. I use your function "sequence_id()" in admin.py overriding save_model